# Как получить доступ к property, определенному в классе, использующему Q_GADGET?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, metaclass

То есть, имеем класс, **не** наследующий QObject:

```
class Apply
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant func READ func WRITE setFunc)
public:
    Apply();

    QVariant func() const;
    void setFunc(const QVariant &func);

    ArgContainer args() const;
    void setArgs(const ArgContainer &value);

//    void substitute(ArgContainer actualArgs);

private:
    QVariant _func; //func, name of func, name of a registered action
    ArgContainer _args;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Apply)
```

Проперцию в классе определить можно, как и обещано в документации по `Q_GADGET`. Как теперь получить к ней доступ (не в QML!)?
Пробую так:

```
Apply a;
a.property("func");
```

нет `property()`

Пробую получить доступ к `metaObject`:

```
Apply a;
a.metaObject();
```

нет такого.

Про `staticMetaObject` пишут:

> "staticMetaObject is of type QMetaObject and provides access to the
>   enums declared with Q_ENUMS."

Можно ли его использовать для доступа к проперциям? Если нет, то как прочитать/записать проперцию Q_GADGET'ного класса?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить qmake.

Comment: @maestro пробовал, `property()` не появляется

Comment: а этот класс случайно не в cpp файле находиться?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть класс `Gadget` со свойством `name`:

```
class Gadget{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    QString _name;
public:
    QString name() const{
        qDebug() << "name " << _name;
        return _name;
    }
    void setName(const QString &name){
        qDebug() << "setName " << name;
        _name = name;
    }
};
```

Если вы используете Qt 5.5+, тогда манипулировать этим свойством можно так:

```
Gadget gadget;
Gadget::staticMetaObject.property(0).readOnGadget(&gadget); //name  ""
Gadget::staticMetaObject.property(0).writeOnGadget(&gadget, "newName"); //setName  "newName"
```

Если честно, не очень удобно. Я бы написал собственные методы аналогичные методами из `QObject`:

```
class Gadget{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    QString _name;
public:
    QString name() const{
        qDebug() << "name " << _name;
        return _name;
    }
    void setName(const QString &name){
        qDebug() << "setName " << name;
        _name = name;
    }
    QVariant property(const char *name) const{
        int index = staticMetaObject.indexOfProperty(name);
        if(index == -1){
            return QVariant();
        }

        return staticMetaObject.property(index).readOnGadget(this);
    }
    bool setProperty(const char *name, const QVariant &value){
        int index = staticMetaObject.indexOfProperty(name);
        if(index == -1){
            return false;
        }

        return staticMetaObject.property(index).writeOnGadget(this, value);
    }
};
```

Если у вас такой класс всего один, то на этом можно бы и остановиться. Но если таких классов много, то нужно как-то все это обобщить.
**Первый вариант**. Дополнить макрос `Q_GADGET`:

```
#define MY_GADGET     Q_GADGET \
                  public: \
                      QVariant property(const char *name) const{ \
                          int index = staticMetaObject.indexOfProperty(name); \
                          if(index == -1){ \
                              return QVariant(); \
                          }\
                          return staticMetaObject.property(index).readOnGadget(this); \
                      }\
                      bool setProperty(const char *name, const QVariant &value){\
                          int index = staticMetaObject.indexOfProperty(name);\
                          if(index == -1){\
                              return false;\
                          }\
                          return staticMetaObject.property(index).writeOnGadget(this, value);\
                      }\
                   private:
```

Теперь если вместо `Q_GADGET` использовать `MY_GADGET`, то методы `property` и `setProperty` будут всегда под рукой.

**Второй вариант**. Сделать шаблонные функции для работы со свойствами:

```
template<class Gadget>
QVariant property(const char *name, const Gadget &gadget){
    int index = Gadget::staticMetaObject.indexOfProperty(name);
    if(index == -1){
        return QVariant();
    }
    return Gadget::staticMetaObject.property(index).readOnGadget(&gadget);
}

template<class Gadget>
bool setProperty(const char *name, Gadget &gadget, const QVariant &value){
    int index = Gadget::staticMetaObject.indexOfProperty(name);
    if(index == -1){
        return false;
    }
    return Gadget::staticMetaObject.property(index).writeOnGadget(&gadget, value);
}
```